# How do I make part of the script asynchronous with dask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask

Suppose I am given a collection of documents. I am required to tokenize them, and then turn them into vectors for further work. As I find elasticsearch's tokenizer works much better than my own solution, I am switching to that. However, it is considerably slower. Then the end result is expected to be fed into the vectorizer in a stream.

The whole process can be done with a chained list of generators

```
def fetch_documents(_cursor):
    with _cursor:
        # a lot of documents expected, may not fit in memory
        _cursor.execute('select ... from ...')

        for doc in _cursor:
            yield doc

def tokenize(documents):
    for doc in documents:
        yield elasticsearch_tokenize_me(doc)

def build_model(documents):
    some_model = SomeModel()

    for doc in documents:
        some_model.add_document(doc)

    return some_model

build_model(tokenize(fetch_documents))
```

So this basically works fine, but doesn't utilize all the available processing capability. As dask is used in other related projects, I try to adapt and get this (I am using psycopg2 for database access).

```
from dask import delayed
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.client import IndicesClient

def loader():
    conn = psycopg2.connect()

    cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    cur.execute('''
                SELECT document, ... FROM ...
                ''')
    return cur

@delayed
def tokenize(partition):
    result = []

    client = IndicesClient(Elasticsearch())

    for row in partition:
        _result = client.analyze(analyzer='standard', text=row['document'])
        result.append(dict(row,
                           tokens=tuple(item['token'] for item in _result['tokens'])))

    return result

@delayed
def build_model(sequence_of_data):
    some_model = SomeModel()

    for item in chain.from_iterable(sequence_of_data):
        some_model.add_document(item)

    return some_model

with loader() as cur:
    partitions = []

    for idx_start in range(0, cur.rowcount, 200):
        partitions.append(delayed(cur.fetchmany)(200))

    tokenized = []
    for partition in partitions:
        tokenized.append(tokenize(partition))

    result = do_something(tokenized)
    result.compute()
```

Code more or less work, except at the end all documents are tokenized, before being fed into the model. While this works for smaller collection of data, however not for a huge collection of data (due to huge memory consumption). Should I just use plain `concurrent.futures` for this work or am I using dask wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to load data locally on your machine (it's hard to partition a single SQL query) and then send the data to the dask-cluster for the expensive tokenization step.  Perhaps something as follows:

```
rows = cur.execute(''' SELECT document, ... FROM ... ''')

from toolz import partition_all, concat
partitions = partition_all(10000, rows)

from dask.distributed import Executor
e = Executor('scheduler-address:8786')

futures = []

for part in partitions:
    x = e.submit(tokenize, part)
    y = e.submit(process, x)
    futures.append(y)

results = e.gather(futures)
result = list(concat(results))
```

In this example the functions tokenize and process expect to consume and return a list of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Using just `concurrent.futures` for the work

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def loader():
    conn = psycopg2.connect()

    cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    cur.execute('''
                SELECT document, ... FROM ...
                ''')
    return cur

def tokenize(partition):
    result = []

    client = IndicesClient(Elasticsearch())

    for row in partition:
        _result = client.analyze(analyzer='standard', text=row['document'])
        result.append(dict(row,
                           tokens=tuple(item['token'] for item in _result['tokens'])))

    return result

def do_something(partitions, total):
    some_model = 0
    for partition in partitions:
        result = partition.result()

        for item in result:
            some_model.add_document(item)

    return some_model

with loader() as cur, \
    ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    print(cur.rowcount)
    partitions = []

    for idx_start in range(0, cur.rowcount, 200):
        partitions.append(executor.submit(tokenize,
                                          cur.fetchmany(200)))

    build_model(partitions)
```